# swift uitableview moves up after unwind segue

Tags: swift, uitableview, unwind-segue

I have a custom uitableview inside a uiviewcontroller. A segue to another tableviewcontroller will happen every time a cell is tapped on. I also have a back button on the other tableviewcontroller which allows users to segue back to the original viewcontroller. The problem happens when the unwind segue happens. After I get back to the original viewcontroller, the first cell of the tableview would be hidden right below the navigation bar, so the tableview bounds have changed I'm guessing? I have been looking everywhere but am unable to find a solution, please help! thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you certain you are popping back to the original view controller or are you segueing to a new instance of the same view controller?

Comment: My guess is, that you are using self sizing cells and that the size of the cells is different to the estimated size.

Comment: @MattLong i put the unwind segue func in the original view controller so pretty sure i got back to that one instead of a new instance...

Comment: @dasdom can you elaborate on self sizing? sorry i'm quite new to swift. I have custom cell heights for each cell, i have them in heightForRowAtIndexPath and also on storyboard... if the size of the cells is different to the estimated size, how can i fix that? thanks

Comment: If you use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you don't have self-sizing cells. Therefore you can ignore my comment.